# Where and How to edit Kubernetes HPA behaviour

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, hpa, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

It is mentioned here on how edit [Support for configurable scaling behavior](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-configurable-scaling-behavior) on how to edit the Autoscaling behaviour. But I cannot find any YAML file to edit or on how to apply the mentioned changes.

I have 3 Kubernetes Environment :

- Docker Desktop
- Baremetal Kubernetes
- Rancher

May I know how to apply the changes mentioned [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#support-for-configurable-scaling-behavior) in the above environments.

Comment: Since I was using autoscaling/v2beta1 , i was not able to find the template mentioned in the K8 documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run

```
kubectl get hpa -n namespace
```

This will give you the list of current HPAs in effect

Then use

```
kubectl -n namespace edit hpa <hpa_name>
```

and make the desired changes.

Comment: May I know in which section of the template the behavior section comes in?

Comment: check this out: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/nodes/pods/nodes-pods-autoscaling.html#nodes-pods-autoscaling-policies_nodes-pods-autoscaling

Comment: Thanks Rakesh sir, Since I was using autoscaling/v2beta1 , i was not able to find the template mentioned in the K8 documentation.

Comment: I was using apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1, thats why I was not seeing the changes when I used edit command